# Parent router's middleware not being executed in child router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 2 routers in my expressjs server. One is the main one which has the following middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,x-auth-token');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth-token');
  next();
});
```

Then there's this route:
app.use('/restaurants', restaurant_router);

And inside the `restaurant_router` I have:
router.use('/:restaurant_id/orders', restaurant_order_router);

And inside `restaurant_order_router` I have a get request.

Now what happens is, when I send a request `GET /restaurants` it first sends a OPTIONS request because I send `x-auth-token` in headers and then it sends the GET request.

But when I try to use the same headers and send a request to the child router `GET /restaurants/:restaurant_id/order` it fails with 500 and says there is no http ok status.

I looked up the problem and saw that if I add `app.options('*', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));` in the root router it starts working.

Why is this the case? Why do I have to set this options myself? Why doesn't it work like it does with the `GET /restaurants` request?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not sending a proper response in your other route?

Comment: @Aplet123 if that was the case it shouldve given me an error but its not even getting at the GET request, its failing at OPTIONS

Comment: Since OPTIONS requests are handled normally with other routes such as ```GET /restaurants``` then I assume it's not related to the CORS configuration, but perhaps it's related to routes structuring/defining, may you edit the question and add the rest of the code; routes and child routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you add all the relevant code to your question, we could see for sure, but it appears that on the OPTIONS request, you appropriately set the headers in your middleware, but then you don't have any route that sends a 2xx response for the OPTIONS request.  That means it probably falls through to a default 404 handler.

On the other hand, when you added the explicit handler for:

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));
```

then, you were adding something that would return a 200 status for the OPTIONS request.  So, that appears to be the missing piece.  You could also do it this way:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,x-auth-token');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth-token');
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that this middleware is allowing any web page to use this server.  You may want to restrict it to your specific domain.